# how to prevent highcharts tooltip popup from hiding, on graph area or browser window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

After resizing the graph area or browser window, the tool tip popup wont show on mouse-over in highcharts.

```
$(function () {

 $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=large-dataset.json&callback=?', function (data) {

    // Create a timer
    var start = +new Date();

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    if (!window.isComparing) {
                        this.setTitle(null, {
                            text: 'Built chart in ' + (new Date() - start) + 'ms'
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        rangeSelector: {

            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 3,
                text: '3d'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '1w'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 3
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Hourly temperatures in Vik i Sogn, Norway, 2004-2010'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Built chart in ...' // dummy text to reserve space for dynamic subtitle
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: data,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2004, 3, 1),
            pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 1,
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]

    });
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/data-grouping/

Comment: Have you tried chart.redraw() or chart.reflow() on resize? This is weird behavior. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is bug already reported on our bug tracker [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3945). It should be fixed in 4.1.4/2.1.4 versions.

Answer (score -1):

just give chart container width in percentage like below or use redraw() function upon resizing browser window or graph area.

```
<div id="chartcontainer" width='100%'></div>
```

updated chart demo link

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/data-grouping/